# How to do javascript continuous scrolling - automatic loading

Tags: javascript

I am not proficient in JavaScript. and I have no idea what do people call for this method. 
I would like to learn about how does http://imgur.com/gallery/hot load the page continuously as you scroll down the page.

Please take a look at the above URL. I mean you can scroll it as much as you wantm the same as Facebook timeline.

What is this method? Do you know anywhere I can learn this?

Comment: may be you don't know, but there is one fundamental custom on SO - to accept the answers on your questions. without it the concept of this greatest resource makes no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Infinite Scrolling or Continuos Scrolling. Here is the deal: http://designbeep.com/2011/08/12/12-jquery-infinite-scrollingscroll-read-plugins-for-content-navigation/

Comment: Hey naveed, That the thing i am looking for. Thanks alot. Jeremy J thanks for answering

Comment: Most items on that site are now 404. Can we get an updated link for this?